# Find the value of $m$ such that the fourth degree equation has 4 roots in $\mathbb R$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, number-theory, polynomials

Problem :

I was posted this question before and @sjorszini but I don't get complete solution of this 
See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3378632/equation-16x4-alpha-x32-alpha17x2-alpha-x16-0)

Given a equation fourth degree with constant $m$ as following :

$16t^{4}-mt^{3}+(2m+17)t^{2}-mt+16=0$ , $t\in \mathbb R$

Question is determine the value of $m$ such the above equation has 4 roots $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$
And they are geometric sequence

Answer is $m=270$ and roots is $2,8,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{8}$ and they geometric sequence with $q=4$ 
But how we find it value of $m$

My effort is :

Let roots $y,yq,yq^{2},yq^{3}$ with $y≠0$ and $q≠(0/±1)$

So a Assam that $|q|>1$: $|y|<|yq|<|yq^{2}|<|yq^{3}|$

So : $\frac{1}{y},\frac{1}{qy},\frac{1}{yq^{2}},\frac{1}{yq^{3}}$ also roots of equation
Mean : $\frac{1}{y}=qy^{3}$ implies $q=y^{-\frac{2}{3}}$ 
Now I don't know how I complete

Comment: What is $x$ in your first equation ?

Comment: The least you could do is link to the original posting of the question.

Comment: Sorry for mistake type

Comment: See now , I add something

Comment: @Moo , yes answer

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track with your question.

$P(x)=16x^{4}-\alpha x^{3}+(2\alpha+17)x^{2}-\alpha x+16=0$

Let: $x_{1}=b$ , $x_{2}=bq$ , $x_{3}=bq^{2}$ and $x_{4}=bq^{3}$

Now apply Vieta's formulae for a fourth-degree polynomial.

For example, the first equation will be $-16=b(1+q+q^2+q^3)$

Solve the generated system of equations. This will give you the value of $\alpha$, $b$ and $q$.

Comment: thank you very much , but I need see how to solve the system ??

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_1=y,a_2=yq,a_3=yq^2,a_4=yq^3$.

By the [Vieta's theorem](https://brilliant.org/wiki/vietas-formula/):
$$\begin{cases}a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4=\frac{m}{16}\\
a_1a_2+a_1a_3+a_1a_4+a_2a_3+a_2a_4+a_3a_4=\frac{2m+17}{16}\\
a_1a_2a_3+a_1a_2a_4+a_1a_3a_4+a_2a_3a_4=\frac{m}{16}\\
a_1a_2a_3a_4=\frac{16}{16}=1\end{cases} \Rightarrow \\
\begin{cases}y(1+q+q^2+q^3)=\frac{m}{16}\\
y^2q(1+q+2q^2+q^3+q^4)=\frac{2m+17}{16}\\
y^3q^3(1+q+q^2+q^3)=\frac{m}{16}\\
y^4q^6=1\end{cases}\Rightarrow \\
(m,y,q)=(170,\frac18,4),(170,8,\frac14).$$
Wolfram Alpha [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20y%5E4q%5E6%3D1%2Cy%281%2Bq%2Bq%5E2%2Bq%5E3%29%3Dm%2F16%2Cy%5E2q%281%2Bq%2B2q%5E2%2Bq%5E3%2Bq%5E4%29%3D%282m%2B17%29%2F16%2Cy%5E3q%5E3%281%2Bq%2Bq%5E2%2Bq%5E3%29%3D%5Cfrac%7Bm%7D%7B16%7D%20for%20m).

Comment: Thanks , @farruhota can you give some ways to evaluate the last system , how we can find without wolfram ?

Comment: Hint: look at the first and the third equation.